# Getting Mathematical Errors Trying to calculate base price of gas

Tags: c++, math, equation

I am trying to solve a problem that requires me to write code to find the base price of a gallon of gas. I am provided with the cost of a gallon of gas, the amount of federal and state tax, and the percent for sales tax. I've tried formatting the equation a couple different ways and the math is always wrong. This is the closest I've gotten (the output is $3.289 which is only .073 cents off, which when I do the calculations by hand happens to be the amount of sales tax so it is as if it is ignoring the end of the equation completely). Could I please get some assistance? I've included the entire problem I was given below.

```
double pumpPrice=3.89, fedTax=.184, stateTax=.417, salesTax=2.25;
double basePrice, totalTax, percentTax, profit_bigOil ;

basePrice = pumpPrice-fedTax-stateTax-((salesTax*basePrice)/100) ;

cout <<"The base price for a gallon of gas is $" <<basePrice << endl;
```

Create a program, i.e. a Netbeans project with the following inputs

0) Take your pump price, whatever you paid at the pump along with taxes and calculate percentage that you pay in taxes.

```
  Pump Price = Base Price + Fed Tax + State Tax + Base Price * Sales Tax
```

1)  Oil Company Profit ->  https://www.forbes.com/2011/05/10/oil-company-earnings.html#6c3f9a9f2dc8

```
 7cents/gallon to 6.5%/gallon
```

2)  Taxes -> http://www.latimes.com/politics/essential/la-pol-ca-essential-politics-updates-california-s-increased-gas-tax-goes-into-1509552219-htmlstory.html

```
 Fed Tax -> 18.4 cents/gallon           State Tax -> 41.7 cents/gallon           State Sales Tax -> 2.25%
```

Calculate the following

1) The base price for a gallon of gas = $

2) The total tax on a gallon of gas   = $

3) Percentage price due to gas tax    = %

4) Oil Company profit range           = %

Comment: Create a program, i.e. a Netbeans project with the following inputs

0) Take your pump price, whatever you paid at the pump along with taxes and calculate percentage that you pay in taxes.

      Pump Price = Base Price + Fed Tax + State Tax + Base Price * Sales Tax

1)  Oil Company Profit ->  https://www.forbes.com/2011/05/10/oil-company-earnings.html#6c3f9a9f2dc8 

     7cents/gallon to 6.5%/gallon

Comment: 2)  Taxes -> http://www.latimes.com/politics/essential/la-pol-ca-essential-politics-updates-california-s-increased-gas-tax-goes-into-1509552219-htmlstory.html           

     Fed Tax -> 18.4 cents/gallon           State Tax -> 41.7 cents/gallon           State Sales Tax -> 2.25%

Calculate the following 

1) The base price for a gallon of gas = $

2) The total tax on a gallon of gas   = $

3) Percentage price due to gas tax    = %

4) Oil Company profit range           = %

Comment: Your statement (`basePrice = ...`) looks like a mathematical equation. However this is not how C++ (or any other imperative language) works. It needs instructions on how to compute `basePrice`, not equations. In this case you're using uninitialized `basePrice` variable in the right-hand side of assignment, which produces undefined behavior

Comment: Ok, I understand that but then how would I write those instructions?

Comment: Alli, now that you've *added* the formula, it appears my assumption was correct. What you need to do is just realise that `basePrice + basePrice * salesTaxFraction` is the same as `basePrice * (1 + salesTaxFraction)` (as per the distributive law of algebra). Then you only have *one* `basePrice` you need to worry about and the method in my answer will work fine.

Comment: Off-topic:  You'll have better accuracy if you work in pennies and not dollars (actually, you may want to work in units of 1/100 penny).  Keep things as integers until you print.

Answer (score 2):

```
   basePrice = pumpPrice-fedTax-stateTax-((salesTax*basePrice)/100) ;
// ^^^^^^^^^                                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

That statement is attempting to *set* `basePrice` so it's probably a bad idea to *use* the uninitialised `basePrice` in the calculation.

Methinks you need to work out the formula you need to use before translating that into code. A good start would be to take the base price and document how each of the taxes is applied to it to get the pump price. Then it's a simple matter of reversing that process.

For example (and I have no idea if this is actually how you US bods do it with your overly complex tax system), let's say that the base price has sales tax of 2.25% applied, and then the absolute values of state and federal taxes added. That would mean:

```
pumpPrice = basePrice * (1 + salesTax / 100) + stateTax + federalTax
```

The reverse of that (working out base price from pump price) would come from:

```
   pumpPrice = basePrice * (1 + salesTax / 100) + stateTax + federalTax
=> pumpPrice - federalTax = basePrice * (1 + salesTax / 100) + stateTax   [*a]
=> pumpPrice - federalTax - stateTax = basePrice * (1 + salesTax / 100)   [*b]
=> (pumpPrice - federalTax - stateTax) / (1 + salesTax / 100) = basePrice [*c]
```

<sup>[*a]</sup> Subtract federal tax from both sides.
<sup>[*b]</sup> Subtract state tax from both sides.
<sup>[*c]</sup> Divide both sides by sales tax (adjusted) rate.

And, voila, swap the sides and you have your formula:

```
basePrice = (pumpPrice - federalTax - stateTax) / (1 + salesTax / 100)
```

Comment: I understand that but I don't see any other way to do it. Maybe my understanding of the question as a whole is wrong.

Comment: I just added a comment with the entire problem

Comment: @AlliVanzant, apologies but, without the actual process used for converting base to pump price, that comment's about as useful as "Given the xyzzy and plugh, calculate the twisty factor" :-)

Comment: Sorry the entire comment didn't load. I feel like I'm stuck here. I can't get sales tax without base price and can't get base price without sales tax and it just doesn't seem to be doable. I've been trying all weekend

Comment: @AlliVanzant: In your question, you say you're given the sales tax percentage. You only have one unknown, not two.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I am given the sales tax percentage but not the sales tax itself.

Comment: @AlliVanzant: paxdiablo's answer assumes that. It's using the percentage as part of the calculation.